# Which JDK Distribution is pre-installed in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Which JDK(Oracle OpenJDK, Oracle JDK, Amazon Correto ...) is pre-installed in Eclipse?
I found I can change JREs and compilers from [Window]/[Preference].

Comment: Thank you for some answers. I installed Pleiades all in one, which contains JDKs and Japanese plugin, so I didn't install JDK itself. Pleiades seems to use AdoptOpenJDK.

Comment: upvote answers if they were helpful in anyway :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does not have any pre-installed JDK.

A suitable Java must be installed before you can install Eclipse.

You can configure Eclipse to use any JRE/JDK that you have installed for each of your projects. You can tell Eclipse about multiple Java installations.

Eclipse has its own Java compiler which can be set to be compliant with the different releases of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer for more information on eclipse installation here [https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation][1], JREs and JDKs are installed on eclipse on a need basis, so **none is pre-installed**.

An instruction from the eclipse wiki:

> If you intend to use Eclipse for Java development, then you should
>   install a JDK. If you aren't planning to use Eclipse for Java
>   development and want to save some disk space, install a JRE

These Installation instructions for all platforms will make your life easy:http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~cs1301/JavaInstall.html